# Multisampling for drawing app

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

I'm creating a drawing iOS application, and in need of smoothing the lines being drawn by user.
I'm using multisampling as normal.

For each time a user moves their finger, the code is like this :

1. Create points to make a line and then draw these points to a sampling buffer.
2. Resolve the sampling buffer.
3. The result buffer is drawn to the canvas.

The problem is when user have a big canvas (e.g: 2048x2048), the resolve process takes quite a time that it's causing the drawing to lag/choppy. The resolve process will resolve all the pixels in the buffer, regardless whether that pixels needs to be resolved or not.

I saw a drawing app like Procreate, and it draws smoothly with no lag even for a big canvas.

So, it is possible, I just don't know how to do that.

Does anybody have an idea for solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone has the same problem with me, I found a decent solution :

1. Create a smaller sampling FBO just for the purpose of drawing the lines from last point to the current point. I use a 256x256 buffer.
2. When drawing from the last point to the current point, use this sampling buffer and then resolve.
3. Draw this sampling buffer to the current layer.

The result is not bad, no more lag. The only problem is that setting the appropriate transform, matrix, etc is quite hard.